# How complex is a spectrograph to design and produce?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

I am interested in exploring multi-spectral imaging, particularly in the (mysterious, invisible) near infrared. I have seen that you can turn a monochrome area scan camera of MxN pixels into a multi-spectral line-scan camera of M spatial by N spectral pixels... so long as you have a spectrograph to split and spread the wavelengths you are interested in... and an area scan camera sensitive to those wavelengths (e.g. silicon sensors will handle visible range; InGaAs sensors will handle near infrared range).

At this stage, a spectrograph is a black box to me. I imagine it would involve some arrangement of optical components (lenses, gratings, mirrors, ...) mounted with sufficient precision and housed in a suitable enclosure. I expect it would need calibration to know which pixels responded to which wavelengths - that you couldn't just expect to mount the components so precisely that pixel X would inevitably represent wavelength Y, rather than Y +/- some unknown error requiring calibration and downstream compensation.

Nonetheless... that sounds like a project that someone with a degree in Physics might reasonably expect to design and assemble themselves, even without a background in optics. Is that overly-optimistic? Can anyone provide or recommend a useful guide to building a spectrograph by oneself... as opposed to spending thousands purchasing one?

Comment: There are lots of optics books out there that describe spectrometers, as well as lots of product literature for you to look over. Building a simple spectrometer for home use is fairly easy - the grating could just be a DVD for example. Building one for true multi-spectral imaging is significantly tougher. As a staff member of mine once said, multi-spectral techniques are really good at showing just how bad your optics design is.

Comment: I'd like to add that there are several DIY tutorials online. I remember there were also some kits available online, or simple instructions using a shoe box and a CD/DVD.

Comment: Can anyone provide references to such optics books or DIY tutorials? I can see that you could make a toy device reasonably easily... but I want something I could make quantitative measurements with - something worth calibrating and/or worth considering paying at least hundred for. I'm not interested in cardboard and duct-tape construction - 3-D printing at a minimum.

Comment: You can certainly build a spectrograph: I built an echelle spectrograph as shown in my answer [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49116/45954) and the link therein. Mine is for 400 to 700 nm, but the IR could be accessed by using IR capable collimation and using IR sensors or IR cameras. It is a fair bit of work, especially the calibration, lots of fun learning how spectrographs, spectrometers and spectroscopes really work. Best of success if you go for it!

Comment: I built a second echelle spectrograph here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/175028/79678. Like my first one, it is for the visible spectral range. I could extend the range to the IR by doing what I suggested in my other comment. If you do build a spectrograph, forget the DVD or CD-RW “grating” and the cereal box housing. Those are toys and all but useless.